# Rails: how to style submit tag with custom css

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

The code below creates a form and styles the "submit" button according to some css ("button").  The problem is, when the page renders, it shows the normal rails submit tag button *on top of* the customized "button" css.  How do I mute or disable the visual aspects of the rails submit tag button while still making it submit the form?

```
=form_tag new_site_url, :method => :get do
  =text_field_tag :homepage,'', type: "text", class: 'text'
  %button
    =submit_tag "GO!"
```

Comment: Can you give the html generate and your css?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you do this :

```
=form_tag new_site_url, :method => :get do
  =text_field_tag :homepage,'', type: "text", class: 'text'
  =submit_tag "GO!", class: 'button'
```

and set the css style for the button?

It better to do this :

```
=form_tag new_site_url, :method => :get do |f|
  =f.text_field '', type: "text", class: 'text'
  =f.submit "GO!", class: 'button'
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way is (rails 4.1)

```
<%= submit_tag("Submit", :class => "btn btn-warning" ) %>
```

Here is where you go to find answers http://api.rubyonrails.org/

and if you are working in form_for you would do

```
<%= f.submit("Submit", class: "btn btn-default" ) %>
```

Comment: These classes are not built into Rails like you suggest. These are built into Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/), which must be added to your Rails app in order for you to use it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using old school ruby(1.8.7) and rails(2.3.5)

heres what my submit tags look like for custom css styling :

```
<%= submit_tag("Edit", :style => "width:30px;") %>
```

where "Edit" is the text that appears on the button, and "width:30px;" is my styling. you can also cascade the stylings :

```
<%= submit_tag("Edit", :style => "width:30px;color:blue;") %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a style key to the hash

```
<p><%= submit_tag l(:button_apply), :class => 'btn btn-default btn-sm', :name => 'submit', :style => 'margin-left: 42px' %></p>
```